# Access violation error when quitting game with Box2D physics in C++

Tags: c++, game-physics, game-development, box2d

I'm currently developing my own C++ game using Box2D physics. However, when I try to quit the game, I encounter an access violation error with the following message:

> "Exception error at 0x003A2AE4 in NinjaPlatformer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation while reading at position 0xFEEEFEF2"

The error seems to be occurring at the line `b2Contact* c = ce->contact;` in the following code snippet:

```
for (b2ContactEdge* ce = body->GetContactList(); ce != nullptr; ce = ce->next) {
    // Value of "ce" crash: 0xfeeefeee {other=??? contact=??? prev=??? ...}

    b2Contact* c = ce->contact;
    // Value of "c" at crash: 0x07932d78 {m_type=b2_dynamicBody | -17891604 (-17891602) m_flags=65262 m_islandIndex=-17891602 ...} 
    
    if (c->IsTouching()) {
        // something
    }
 }
```

I guess that when attempting to close the application, the body contacts are deleted before the program loops back to the for loop, resulting in an error because the body is no longer defined. Is this correct? If so, how can I check within the for loop if `ce` is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be care about edge conditions: the last valid b2ContactEdge* ce in your list has no initialized "next" member.

"next" has a invalid value 0xFEEEFEF2 at the last ce in your list.

I suggest you add this constructor a your b2ContactEdge class:

```
b2ContactEdge() { next = NULL; }
```

Comment: And then in my code I can as, if its equal to NULL?

Comment: Wow, it worked. b2ContactEdge doesn't have a constructor, because it's only a struct but I added it to the struct and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much! :)